# I want to get a page chapter like the image below

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
%%%%%%%%%%%% En-tête et pied de page

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{main}

%%%%%%%%%%%% Définitions par défaut
\newcommand{\intro}[1]{\def\chapterintro{#1}}
\newcommand{\introauthor}[1]{\def\chapterintroauthor{#1}}
\introauthor{} % auteur de la citation en début de chapitre
\intro{} % Citation en début de chapitre ; à déclarer avant la commande \chapter{}


%%%%%%%%%%%% Page de présentation

%%%%%%%%%%%% Première page de chaque chapitre

\titleformat{\chapter}
{%
    \thispagestyle{chapterstart}
    \pagecolor{white}
    \bfseries\Huge\raggedleft
    \color{chapter@title@color}
    \chaptertitle@font
}
{%
  \AddToShipoutPicture
  {%
    \put(\LenToUnit{0mm},\LenToUnit{0mm})
    {%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \clip (0,0) rectangle+(\paperwidth,-\paperheight);
        % Rectangle du haut à droite
        \fill[bottom color=chapterdegrade@color,top color=white] (0,0) rectangle+(\paperwidth,-3);
        % Trait en biais dans le rectangle en haut à droite
        \draw[chapterline@color] (0,3) -- (\paperwidth,-3);
        % Petit cercle vide dans le rectangle en haut à droite
        \draw[chapterline@color,very thick,opacity=0.5] (.8\paperwidth,-2) circle (5mm);
        % Petit cercle rempli dans rectangle haut croit
        \fill[chaptertopcircle@color] ($(.8\paperwidth,-2)+(8mm,8mm)$) circle (2mm);
        % Citation éventuelle
        \ifx\chapterintro\@empty
        \else
              \node[below left,text=chapterintro@color] (citation) at (21,-0.5) {\og \emph{\chapterintro} \fg{}};
              \ifx\chapterintroauthor\@empty
              \else
                 \node[below left,text=chapterintro@color] at (citation.south east) {(\chapterintroauthor)};
              \fi
        \fi
        % cercle vide en bas à gauche
        \fill[chapterbotcircle@color] (1,-27) circle (3cm);
        \fill[white] (1,-27) circle (2.5cm);
        % Petit cercle presque centré verticalement
        \fill[chaptermidcircle@color] (1.2,-17) circle (.7cm);
        \fill[white] (1.2,-17) circle (0.6cm);
         % Traits verticaux à gauche
        \draw[very thick,chapterrule@color] (1cm,0) -- (1cm,-\paperheight);
        \draw[very thick,chapterrule@color] (1.2cm,0) -- (1.2cm,-\paperheight);
        % Ellipse en haut à gauche
        \fill[chapterellipse@bg@color] (0,0) ellipse[x radius=9cm,y radius=5cm];
        % Ombre de l'ellipse
        \foreach \rx/\ry/\c in { %
        8.7/4.7/10,% 
        8.66/4.66/30,%
        8.62/4.62/50,%
        8.58/4.58/70,%
        8.54/4.54/90%
        }
        {
        \fill[fill=black!\c!chapterellipse@bg@color] (0,0) ellipse[x radius=\rx cm,y radius=\ry cm];
        }
        % ellipse
        \fill[chapterellipse@color] (0,0) ellipse[x radius=8.5cm,y radius=4.5cm];    
        % Dans l'ellipse en haut à gauche ...
        \clip (0,0) ellipse[x radius=8.5cm,y radius=4.5cm];
         % Traits verticaux à gauche
        \draw[very thick,chapterrule@color] (1cm,0) -- (1cm,-\paperheight);
        \draw[very thick,chapterrule@color] (1.2cm,0) -- (1.2cm,-\paperheight);
        \fill[chapter@bg@color] (0,-0.8) rectangle+(15,-1.3);
        \node[text=chaptertitlename@color,right] at (0.1,-1.5) {\huge\chaptertitlename@font\bfseries\chaptertitlename~\thechapter};
  \end{tikzpicture}
       }
  }
}
{7ex}
{}
```

[image]

Comment: Did Blaise Pascal really say so? ;o)

Comment: I did not anderstand _Bernard

Comment: I was just joking about Pascal's citation in the image.

Comment: I guss he  do said that

Comment: we heed a preamble \documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document} did not work for me

Comment: if you can give me your email I'll sand you the fill it containe  the fill source of this book    KJO

Comment: @WalidTex Please don't send the whole source code to any user privately, and also please don't show the whole source code publicly. You should show a minimal but compilable example that can reproduce your problem (aka [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/156344)).

Comment: okay no problem